# How do I get Banshee to work with my Android 4.4.2 device?

Tags: android, sync, music, banshee

I have a new Galaxy S5 (SC-04), with Android 4.4.2. When I plug it in as an MTP media device, it's visible in Nautilus (Gnome Flashback, Ubuntu 14.04) and I can browse and edit files and folders no problem.

In Banshee 2.6.2, though, there are many problems. It takes a long time, 5 to 10 minutes for the Android to appear in the Banshee interface. When it does, it does not recognize any of the existing music folders or files. If I try to sync, it outputs an error saying the sync failed for each music file, and then Banshee crashes.

How do I get Banshee to sync with my Android Device?

---

As requested in comments, I ran `banshee > output` at the command line. This time, I had the Samsung attached before starting Banshee, which seemed to prevent the Samsung from appearing in the Nautilus interface. Eventually Banshee crashed. Here is the contents of the `output` file:

```
[Info  13:37:21.765] Running Banshee 2.6.2: [Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2014-08-12 14:04:38 UTC]
[Info  13:37:23.143] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Info  13:37:23.175] All services are started 1.097818
[Info  13:37:24.325] nereid Client Started
[Info  13:37:24.419] GStreamer version 1.2.4.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False
[Warn  13:38:10.893] Failed to load media-player-info file for 1
[Warn  13:38:10.926] Failed to load media-player-info file for 1
```

I can't seem to get the Samsung to even appear in the Banshee interface right now, which is different from other times. I will keep trying, but if the above output reveals anything, please let me know.

---

Update 2: I was able to get the Samsung to appear in Banshee, and I attempted a sync. The output was lenghty, and so I've [placed it here on Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8287643/). I hope that contains some useful information.

Output from `lsusb -vd 04e8:6860` is [here on Pastebin as well](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8287650/).

Here is the output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog > some_file` after connecting the device:

```
Sep  8 14:42:09 dave-laptop NetworkManager[857]: <info>   nameserver '103.5.140.11'
Sep  8 14:42:09 dave-laptop NetworkManager[857]: <info>   nameserver '103.5.140.12'
Sep  8 14:42:09 dave-laptop NetworkManager[857]: <info>   domain name 'wi2.ne.jp'
Sep  8 14:42:09 dave-laptop dbus[686]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Sep  8 14:42:09 dave-laptop dbus[686]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  8 14:42:52 dave-laptop wpa_supplicant[1229]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  8 14:42:57 dave-laptop wpa_supplicant[1229]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Sep  8 14:43:46 dave-laptop kernel: [11242.754380] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
Sep  8 14:43:46 dave-laptop colord: device removed: sysfs-(null)
Sep  8 14:43:46 dave-laptop colord: device removed: sysfs-SAMSUNG-SAMSUNG_Android
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop kernel: [11271.999851] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop kernel: [11272.017478] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop kernel: [11272.017488] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop kernel: [11272.017493] usb 3-2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop kernel: [11272.017498] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop kernel: [11272.017502] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 4ce88c0d
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop colord: Device added: sysfs-SAMSUNG-SAMSUNG_Android
Sep  8 14:44:15 dave-laptop colord: Device added: sysfs-(null)
```

Out from `ps aux | grep -i [m]tp`:

```
dave      2348  0.0  0.1 218368  4176 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
dave      5110  0.1  0.1 446628  3956 ?        Sl   11:52   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp --spawner :1.3 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2
```

---

Not a solution at all, but, if I completely disable the MTP plugin in banshee, then switch my phone to PTP mode, then I can transfer some files. However, for some reason this method causes some process to eat up memory, and if I try to tansfer too many files, the memory overflows and Banshee crashes. So, I can get about 300 to 500 songs transferred, but no more.

Comment: try
 Update banshee

Comment: @totti, I believe I have the latest version. Any version after 2.6.2 is an unstable development version.

Comment: It might be useful to get some lower level information here. Why don't you run `banshee > some_file`, plug in your Android, try to sync, and then give us the contents of `some_file`. It might be useful to watch `dmesg` when you plug in your G5 and see what information it may provide. It's likely either an issue with Banshee or perhaps kernel support of the device.

Comment: @wxl, thank you for responding. I've added some of the output you requested to the question.

Comment: that's useful but not informative with the device already being attached. please unattach and try again. it would also be useful to see what the system logger is giving you. `tail -f /var/log/syslog > some_file` before you attach the device. after you have attached the device, exit the command with Ctrl-C and include the output. also, perhaps we can get some more information on the device with `lsusb -vd 04e8:6860`, assuming that's the appropriate vendor and device IDs for your G5 (confirm with `lsusb | grep Samsung | awk '{print $6}'`.

Comment: @wxl, I've added more output to the question, with hopefully more useful information.

Comment: that's a lot of info to simply explain that it couldn't get the battery level :) for the time being, let's ignore Banshee and look at the other options i mentioned above.

Comment: @wxl, thanks for your continued help. I've tried to add all the output you've requested so far. Please see the question for the latest updated info.

Comment: i believe that `lsusb` actually pulls info from `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` so the fact that it says it uses MTP does not mean that it *is* using MTP currently. the fact that i don't see `mtp-probe` saying anything in your `syslog` makes me concerned. what output, if anything does `ps aux | grep -i [m]tp` give you?

Comment: @wxl, Thanks for your continued help. I've added the `grep` output you suggested to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17019/discussion-between-wxl-and-dave-m-g).

Comment: Sad this bounty didn't get claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Try what I did. Open preferences in Banshee and disable the Apple Products in the plugins section. As soon as I did that my GS4 showed up and I could sync to it. I'm not sure if it helped but as mentioned in another (much older) thread I created a file .is_audio_player on the root directory of my external sd card and the phone memory. I just used the free ES File Explorer app to do that. I'm also using openSUSE 13.1 but I was having the same problem as you.

I made a playlist named "Android" and set Banshee to sync that to my phone. Now the phone only has what I put on that playlist.